# Automatic POST requests validator Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using express-validator and I'm trying to create a middleware that applies to every post request, finds the right validator for the request and calls the right method for the validation.
The validators are objects, exported from files in the /validators folder, the names of the files are related to the requests so that the validation midlleware can import the right validator from the request's path (ex: the validator for the post to /auth/checkSignup is the file /validators/auth.js);
each validator has one (or more) validation method called 'check' where actionName is a part of the request's path (in the example above 'checkSignup' is the action, so the AuthValidator has the method checkLogin).

ex of thw middleware called in the app.js file:

```
app.post(
    '*',
    ValidationDispatcher.validationMiddleware
);
```

the middleware should read the req.path and find the appropriate validator for the route (eg: the pathg is /auth/signup the validator is the one exported by the file auth.js, leaving out the folders),

the actual code:

```
validationMiddleware: (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            const pathSections = req.path.split("/");
            const base = pathSections.length > 1 ? pathSections[1] : null;
            const action = pathSections.length > 2 ? pathSections[2] : null;

            if (base) {
                const validator = require(`./${base}`);

                let method = "check";
                if (action) {
                    method += action.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + action.slice(1);
                }

                return validator[method]();
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

after that it should find the appropriate method (in the example above, the method is checkSignup); every method for the validation is similar to this:

```
checkSignup() {
        return expressValidator.checkSchema({
            email: {
                ...this.baseEmailSchema,
                custom: {
                    options: (value) => {
                        return UsersController.getByEmail(value).then((res) => {
                            return res != null;
                        });
                    },
                    errorMessage: "user with this email already exists",
                },
            },
            password: this.basePasswordSchema,
            confirmPassword: {
                custom: {
                    options: (value, { req }) => {
                        return value === req.body.password;
                    },
                    errorMessage: "passwords have to match",
                },
            },
        });
    }
```

but with this approach I'm returning a middleware that will not be executed;
does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: "but with this approach I'm returning a middleware that will not be executed" You're not showing us anything really related to this... What's the value of "ValidationDispatcher.validationMiddleware"? Where is checkSignup() coming from and how /where is it called?

Comment: The middleware should not directly return the result of checkSchema. Instead, it should return a function that Express can execute as middleware. This function should then call the validation checks and use next() to pass control to the next middleware in the stack.